# how to shrink the scale of storm cluster (offline one supervisor machine)

Tags: apache-storm

as the title.

I has a storm cluster with 20 machines, one for nimbus, and 19 for supervisor.
Now I found that we don't need so many machines for storm cluster, and want to offline 2 supervisor machines.

I don't know how to do that gently, just stop the supervisor process in the 2 machines? But there are some executors which are for online service running in this two machines.

Any suggestions will be helpful, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am writing from memory here, so please try this out on a non-production cluster before you go do it and find out I misremembered something.

If your topologies are written to handle message loss (i.e. they either don't care about at-least-once, or you're using acking), you can just kill the supervisor and workers. Nimbus will figure out that the supervisor is dead and reassign the executors pretty quickly. When the new executors come up, the topologies will handle the lost messages as they weren't acked.

If you can't handle message loss, you can deactivate the topologies in Storm UI, wait for them to stop processing and kill the supervisor. Then reactivate the topologies and Nimbus will reassign them.